# Proof for the length of plane curves

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-writing, riemann-sum, arc-length

Given that the plane curve is a parametric curve with equations $x=f(t)$ and $y=g(t)$ and we are finding the length of the curve in the interval (a,b) and so we divide the given plane curve into smaller arcs and write the length of the plane curve as an approximation of this sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt {\Delta x_k^2 + \Delta y_k^2}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt {(f(t_k)-f(t_{k-1}))^2 + (g(t_k)-g(t_{k-1}))^2}$$

As per the mean value theorem ther are numbers such that  $t_k^*$ and $t_k^{**} \in [t_{k-1},t_{k}] $

$$\Delta x_k = f(t_k)-f(t_{k-1})=f^|(t_k^*)\Delta t_k$$

$$ \Delta y_k = g(t_k)-g(t_{k-1})=g^|(t_k^{**})\Delta t_k$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt {f^|(t_k^*)^2 + g^|(t_k^{**})^2}\Delta t_k$$

**My question**

The above equation is not a riemann sum but a theorem in advanced calculus guarantees its limit as the norm of the partition tends to zero (This is what I read in the Thomas Calculus) and I want to know the proof(How does the above sum conerges to below integral) of this and any book to such advanced topics and any links to such.

As the norm of the partition tends to zero the sum conerges to the integral

$$\int_a^b \sqrt {[f^|(t)]^2+[g^|(t)]^2}dt$$

Any type of help is appreciated

Comment: If $f'$ and $g'$ are continuous, it is relatively easy to see - the difference between your sum and a Riemann sum is then shown to converge to zero as the partition norm tends to zero.

Comment: It would be thankful of you if you would elaborate your point.... And also on how can one express the sum as Riemann sum @ThomasAndrews

Comment: And yes intuitively I understand what is happening there as the norm tends to zero but I would like to know how this is actually proved. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: This sort of thing is much easier in the Lebesgue setting, where you can consider the sum in your second equation as an integral over suitable step functions and use the dominated convergence theorem. (In fact, there's really not any terrible compelling reason to cover the Riemann integral first, and possibly even at all; it sacrifices power and clarity without any real benefit.)

Comment: It will be very helpful and interesting to answer this even in Lebesgue setting. I would learn more things @anamoly Any type of help is always welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assume some good behaviour of $f'$ and $g'$: let's say, that $f'$ and $g'$ are continuous on $[a,b]$ (and therefore, by the [Heine-Cantor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem), uniformly continuous on that interval).

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, and take $\delta$ such that for all $s,t \in [a,b]$ with $|s - t| < \delta$, $|f'(s) - f'(t)| < \epsilon$ and $|g'(s)-g'(t)| < \epsilon$.  Let $a = t_0 < t_1 < \ldots < t_n = b$ such that
$t_{j+1} - t_j < \delta$, and let $x_j = f(t_j)$ and $y_j = g(t_j)$.
We write $\Delta x_j = x_{j+1} - x_j$, and similarly for $\Delta y_j$ and $\Delta t_j$.
By the Mean Value Theorem, for each $j$ we have 
$ \Delta x_j = f'(c) \Delta t_j$ with $c \in [t_j, t_{j+1}]$. 
Now $|f'(c) - f'(t_j)| < \epsilon$ so
$$  |\Delta x_j - f'(t_j)\Delta t_j| < \epsilon \Delta t_j$$
and similarly 
$$  |\Delta y_j - g'(t_j)\Delta t_j| < \epsilon \Delta t_j$$ 
By the Triangle Inequality,

$$ \eqalign{\left|\sqrt{(\Delta x_j)^2 + (\Delta y_j)^2} - \sqrt{f'(t_j)^2 + g'(t_j)^2)} \Delta t_j \right| &\le \sqrt{(\Delta x_j - f'(t_j)\Delta t_j)^2 + 
(\Delta y_j - g'(t_j)\Delta t_j)^2}\cr &< \sqrt{2} \epsilon \Delta t_j}$$
so that
$$ \left|\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sqrt{(\Delta x_j)^2 + (\Delta y_j)^2} - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sqrt{f'(t_j)^2 + g'(t_j)^2)} \Delta t_j \right| < \sqrt{2} \epsilon \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \Delta t_j = \sqrt{2} (b-a) \epsilon$$

As $n \to \infty$ with the mesh size $\to 0$, $$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sqrt{f'(t_j)^2 + g'(t_j)^2)} \Delta t_j  \to L = \int_a^b \sqrt{f'(t)^2 + g'(t)^2}\; dt$$ i.e. if $n$ is sufficiently large and $\delta$ is sufficiently small, 
$$ \left| \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sqrt{f'(t_j)^2 + g'(t_j)^2)} \Delta t_j - L \right| < \epsilon $$
so that 
$$  \left|\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sqrt{(\Delta x_j)^2 + (\Delta y_j)^2} - L \right| < (\sqrt{2} (b-a) + 1) \epsilon $$

Comment: Firstly I am delightful that I am getting help from such a person and secondly Thank-you for answering so early. Sir I have understood the answer upto the step before the line "As $n→∞$ with the mesh size $→0$". How would you show that $$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sqrt{f'(t_j)^2 + g'(t_j)^2)} \Delta t_j  \to L = \int_a^b \sqrt{f'(t)^2 + g'(t)^2}\; dt$$ I am able to see this intuitively but again how would one prove this. If I am able to understand this then I will get the whole answer....

Comment: The restrictions on $f$ and $g$ are minor from my viewing angle and I thought it would be much more..... Enjoying to see that.

Comment: @Jasser That's just the convergence of Riemann sums to the integral.  Note that $\sqrt{f'(t)^2 + g'(t)^2}$ is continuous since $f'$ and $g'$ are continuous.

Comment: If we find the upper and lower sum of the length of the arc(as we find in approximating areas) and if they both converge to a single value L then we say that Riemann sum converges to a single value $L$ or Alternatively as you said its just the convergence of Riemann integral....we just have to find a particular $\delta$ for a given $\epsilon$.... Thankyou... got it.